# SceneKit rotating a node with torque yields different vectors than through animation

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am rotating a SCNNode with a SCNPhysics body along the Z by applying torque every update cycle.

```
func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    print(box.presentationNode.rotation)
    box.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(0, 0, 1, 0.06), impulse: false)
}
```

Also every update cycle I'm printing out the presentationNode's rotation.  What I am seeing does not make sense to me.  The printout looks like this, condensed with ...

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 0.4)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 0.9)

...

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 4.18)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1, w: 2.09)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1, w: 1.97)

...

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 0)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 0.1)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 0.23)

...

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 4.18)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1, w: 2.09)

So the rotation's 'w' goes from 0 to 4.18 then in 1 update cycle shifts to 2.09 and starts counting down with z in the negative.  When 'w' counts down to zero, z goes positive and it counts up to 4.18 again.

**This is not the same numbers you get if you rotate the box with a SCNAction and print the results**

When you rotate like this

```
box.runAction(SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 0, z: 50, duration: 100))
```

The 'w' goes from 0.0 to 6.28 (2pi) and then counts back down to zero ( which is what makes more sense).  The print out look like this condensed

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 0.4)

...

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 6.28)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1, w: 6.21)

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1, w: 6.15)

...

SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1, w: 0.0)

Please let me know if what I am asking is unclear or you are seeing different results.

Thank you